# Exception not handled as expected in python

Tags: python, exception

I have the following exception handling code:

```py
try:
    jobs1 = await data.get_jobs()
    jobs2 = await user.get_jobs()
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(x) for x in [loop()] + jobs1 + jobs2]
    print(f"{len(tasks)} tasks")
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
except Exception as e:
    e = str(e)
    [x.cancel() for x in tasks]
    if not any([x in e for x in IGNORE_ERRORS]):
        user.log({"error": f"{e} \n {traceback.format_exc()}"})
```

as you can see from the last line, I expect all exceptions to be handled by `user.log` which saves the error in a `log.json` file.

**All exceptions but one were saved to the json file as expected,
which is the following one, it was printed to the console instead:**

```py
data transfer failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 959, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1029, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1104, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1161, in read_frame
    frame = await Frame.read(
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\framing.py", line 68, in read
    data = await reader(2)
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 707, in readexactly
    await self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 501, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
    length = fut.result()
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 826, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 494, in finish_recv
    return ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 121] 信号灯超时时间已到
```

why is this happening?

Comment: The traceback indicates that this error did not originate within the try: block that you presented here (no line of code from the try block is present in the traceback).  Therefore it has occurred elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @PaulCornelius  thanks for the observation, any idea how to resolve this issue? to capture it into my log.json?

Comment: Sorry, I can't guess how to do that.  It appears like it's being raised in the WebSockets package internals, and that it happens in an asyncio Task which the library creates and manages.